# How to write a Dockerfile to include httpd, php, and php libaries?

Tags: php, docker, apache, containers

I am experimenting with Docker and I would like to migrate my web page to Docker container.

Currently, I am running my php web page in a Cent OS box. I use the commands below to complete my server setup:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install -y httpd httpd-tools mod_ssl
sudo systemctl enable httpd 
sudo systemctl start httpd
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum localinstall -y epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
wget https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh ius-release-el7.rpm
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum install -y --enablerepo=ius-archive php55u php55u-devel
sudo yum install -y --enablerepo=ius-archive php55u-opcache php55u-xml php55u-mcrypt php55u-gd php55u-mysql php55u-intl php55u-mbstring php55u-bcmath php55u-soap php55u-pdo php55u-xmlrpc
```

This will basically install Apache `httpd` server and `php` in my machine. Then I will run the command below to copy my web page files inside `webfiles` directory of my user home, to Apache `htdocs` directory:

```
cp webfiles/* /var/www/html/
```

This is working fine. I am experimenting with Docker and I am exploring tutorials. I wrote the `Dockerfile` like below:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/httpd:2.4
COPY ./webfiles/* /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

This will allow me to start the httpd server and deliver files from that container. But I have no idea how to configure php like what I used to to manually. From the documents available online, I think I need to create a Dockerfile like below;

```
FROM php:55-apache
.
.
```

How can I write the `Dockerfile` to include all the manual operations I have explained?